# R flag cases with missingness from regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, glm

When running a regression analysis in R (using glm) cases are removed due to 'missingness' of the data. Is there any way to flag which cases have been removed? I would ideally like to remove these from my original dataframe.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model fit object returned by `glm()` records the row numbers of the data that it excludes for their incompleteness. They are a bit buried but you can retrieve them like this:

```
## Example data.frame with some missing data
df <- mtcars[1:6, 1:5]
df[cbind(1:5,1:5)] <- NA
df
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4           NA   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  NA  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4   NA  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258  NA 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175   NA
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76

## Fit an example model, and learn which rows it excluded
f <- glm(mpg~drat,weight=disp, data=df)
as.numeric(na.action(f))
# [1] 1 3 5
```

Alternatively, to get the row indices without having to fit the model, use the same strategy with the output of `model.frame()`:

```
as.numeric(na.action(model.frame(mpg~drat,weight=disp, data=df)))
# [1] 1 3 5
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just do `as.numeric(f$na.action)` instead of `as.numeric(attr(f$model, "na.action"))`?

Comment: No, there isn't, and it looks like `as.numeric(na.action(f))` works as well. I've just edited the answer to incorporate that info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example I can't provide code tailored to your problem, but here's a generic method that should work. Assume your data frame is called `df` and your variables are called y, x1, x2, etc. And assume you want y, x1, x3, and x6 in your model.

```
# Make a vector of the variables that you want to include in your glm model
# (Be sure to include any weighting or subsetting variables as well, per Josh's comment)
glm.vars = c("y","x1","x3","x6") 

# Create a new data frame that includes only those rows with no missing values
# for the variables that are in your model
df.glm = df[complete.cases(df[ , glm.vars]), ]
```

Also, if you want to see just the rows that have at least one missing value, do the following (note the addition of `!` (the "not" operator)):

```
df[!complete.cases(df[ , glm.vars]), ]
```

Comment: Exactly. Also, if your call to `glm()` uses its `weights` or `subset` arguments, do be sure to include the variables passed to those in `glm.vars`.

Comment: Good point Josh. I've updated my answer to include your comment.

Comment: Many thanks to you both for your help with this question. I have been struggling with this problem for weeks!